# Why is HttpServletRequest inputstream empty?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, guice

I have this code where I read the input from a request input stream and use a JacksonMapper to convert into a POJO. Its running in a jetty 7 container with guice support.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        RequestType requestType = mapper.readValue(req.getInputStream(), RequestType.class);
    } Catch(Exception ex) {
        ....
    }
}
```

However, sometimes under load the following exception is thrown. I have checked my client and I am sure its sending a valid json string. What is going wrong? Is it expected behavior for Jetty 7 under load?

```
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1637)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet.processRequest(LoginServlet.java:69)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:63)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a91c2ebd.CGLIB$doPost$0(<generated>)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a91c2ebd$$FastClassByGuice$$c6f479ee.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:72)
    at com.ea.monitor.MethodExecutionTimer.invoke(MethodExecutionTimer.java:130)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:52)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a91c2ebd.doPost(<generated>)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a91c2ebd.CGLIB$service$8(<generated>)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a91c2ebd$$FastClassByGuice$$c6f479ee.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:72)
    at com.ea.monitor.MethodExecutionTimer.invoke(MethodExecutionTimer.java:130)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:52)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a91c2ebd.service(<generated>)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a91c2ebd.CGLIB$service$9(<generated>)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a91c2ebd$$FastClassByGuice$$c6f479ee.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:72)
    at com.ea.monitor.MethodExecutionTimer.invoke(MethodExecutionTimer.java:130)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:52)
    at com.ea.wsop.user.LoginServlet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a91c2ebd.service(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It will be empty if it's already consumed beforehand. This will be implicitly done whenever you call `getParameter()`, `getParameterValues()`, `getParameterMap()`, `getReader()`, etc on the `HttpServletRequest`. Make sure that you don't call any of those kind of methods which by themselves need to gather information from the request body before calling `getInputStream()`. If your servlet isn't doing that, then start checking the servlet filters which are mapped on the same URL pattern.

---

**Update:** this seems to be GAE 1.5 specific. See also

- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5161
- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5898

I'm afraid that there's no solution/workaround until they get it fixed. You could *try* to check if it's available inside a `Filter` and if so, then copy and store it as request attribute. But this *might* affect further processing by some GAE servlet.

Comment: There is nothing in my code consuming it, but Guice might be doing something under the hood.

Comment: You could *try* to use `getQueryString()` instead, I'm only not sure how GAE acts on "syntactically invalid" query strings.

Comment: Its a post request and I am pulling the data from there.

Comment: You never know on an odd beast as GAE. At least, I googled using "gae request getinputstream" and found several similar problems and bug reports. I included it in my answer.

Comment: This is running on an ec2 instance in jetty 7 not app engine.

Comment: Perhaps EC2 suffers same problems and perhaps it's after all Jetty specific. GAE also uses Jetty under covers.

Comment: Here is the exact issue I am facing. http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/issues/detail?id=45

Comment: The original remarks are correct from BalusC. For further information please look at the Servlet API 3.0 Specification section 3.1 and 3.1.1 which details the behavior noted above.

Comment: See also my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/34280561/21352 which works around another case where Apache Catalina (Tomcat) consumes the input if the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded (even though the controller does not call getParameter(), getParameterValues(), getParameterMap(), getReader() etc.) and how to work around that.

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar problem running a Spring Boot application. My Spring Boot app is a simple `Dispatcher` servlet that reads the request body and processes it.

In my case, the client (`curl`) sets a content-type header of application/x-www-form-urlencoded if the curl  command line uses `-d {some-data}` and does not set an specific content-type header via `-Hcontent-type=some-other-media-type`.

Inside the Apache Catalina servlet engine that Spring Boot runs, the `Request` class makes the following test in `parseParameters()`

```
        if (!("application/x-www-form-urlencoded".equals(contentType))) {
            success = true;
            return;
        }
```

For other `content-type` values, `Request` returns here, done.

However, if the content type **matches** `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `Request` continues:

```
    try {
       if (readPostBody(formData, len) != len) {           
            parameters.setParseFailedReason(FailReason.REQUEST_BODY_INCOMPLETE);
            return;
        }
    } catch (....)
```

which will **consume the body**. So in my case, even though **my** servlet does nothing other than call `request.getInputStream()` and try to `read()` from it, it is already too late - the runtime `Request` already reads the input and does not buffer or unread it. The only workaround is to set a different `Content-Type`.

The culprit is
    `OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter(HiddenHttpMethodFilter).doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain)` line 70

which is looking for the `"_method"` query parameter.

I was able to disable the filter by adding

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration(HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

(which was used to solve [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288910/spring-mvc-controller-method-mapping-using-form-body))

Comment: This is a great discovery, or otherwise, HttpServletRequest in Post handler of controller always returns empty without reason.

Comment: This was a tough one, 2 hours trying to find out why post entity was empty. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

I had the problem that my request InputStream was always empty with Jetty 6.1.15, and found out that it was caused by a missing or wrong "Content-Type" header.

I generate the requests in another Java program with HttpUrlConnection. When I did not set the Content-Type header explicitly, the `InputStream` returned by `request.getInputStream()` in the receiving program was always empty. When I set the content type to "binary/octet-stream", the `InputStream` of the request contained the correct data.

The only method that is called on the request object before `getInputStream()` is `getContentLength()`.

Answer (score 1):

I was using mod_jk 1.2.39 which had a bug that caused this issue. After updating to 1.2.40 it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with a post. I solved it by FIRST reading the inputstream and putting it in a cache, before reading the parameters. That seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Systematic approach is:

1. Get source code for your container, or at least it's web part (can be hard to find), import in your IDE.
2. Make break point in your code where before `HttpServletRequest->getInputStream()` is called.
3. Step into `HttpServletRequest->getInputStream()` method, now you are in some ...Impl class.
4. Set a new break point in that `getInputStream()` implemmentation, or even in its `read()` method.
5. Repeat test call and see what is consuming your data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the problem when enabling debug logging for `org.springframework` in a Spring Boot 2.2.1 project, and thus using spring-webmvc 5.2.1.

This is caused by the request logging of the parameter-map, which reads the input stream if the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I believe [this spring issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22985) is related to it.

See the following code which causes the problem.

```java
private void logRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    LogFormatUtils.traceDebug(logger, traceOn -> {
        String params;
        if (isEnableLoggingRequestDetails()) {
            params = request.getParameterMap().entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + ":" + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        }
        else {
            params = (request.getParameterMap().isEmpty() ? "" : "masked");
        }
...
```

[source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L955)

I ended up reporting [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24176) and and changing the content-type in the request instead.