# Requesting URL parameter breaks inputstream Java

Tags: java, servlets, parameters, request

I have a servlet that accepts POST requests, and it works perfectly when I'm not trying to read parameters. The inputstream contains an XML file which parses just fine. However, when I try to read a parameter:

```
String account = request.getParameter("account");
```

It fails when reading the inputstream.
How can this possibly affect the inputstream?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using a HttpServletRequest and from the [ServletRequest#getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) documentation:

`If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via getInputStream() or getReader() can interfere with the execution of this method.`

Are you using either `getInputStream()` or `getReader()` prior to your `getParameter()` ?

A related answer here might help you solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129256/1524381