# Spring MVC - Why not able to use @RequestBody and @RequestParam together

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post, http-post, http-request-parameters

Using HTTP dev client with Post request and Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

#### 1) Only @RequestBody

URL: localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome
Body: name=abc

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printWelcome(@RequestBody String body, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", body);
    return "hello";
}
// Gives body as 'name=abc' as expected
```

#### 2) Only @RequestParam

URL: localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome
In Body - name=abc

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printWelcome(@RequestParam String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "hello";
}
// Gives name as 'abc' as expected
```

#### 3) Both together

URL: localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome
Body: name=abc

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printWelcome(
    @RequestBody String body, 
    @RequestParam String name, Model model) 
{
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    model.addAttribute("message", body);
    return "hello";
}
// HTTP Error Code 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

#### 4) Above with params position changed

URL: localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome
Body: name=abc

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printWelcome(
    @RequestParam String name, 
    @RequestBody String body, Model model) 
{
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    model.addAttribute("message", body);
    return "hello";
}
// No Error. Name  is 'abc'. body is empty
```

#### 5) Together but get type url parameters

URL: localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome?name=xyz
Body: name=abc

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printWelcome(
    @RequestBody String body, 
    @RequestParam String name, Model model) 
{
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    model.addAttribute("message", body);
    return "hello";
}
// name is 'xyz' and body is 'name=abc'
```

#### 6) Same as 5) but with parameters position changed

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printWelcome(
    @RequestParam String name, 
    @RequestBody String body, Model model) 
{
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    model.addAttribute("message", body);
    return "hello";
}
// name = 'xyz,abc' body is empty
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `@RequestBody` javadoc states

> Annotation indicating a method parameter should be bound to the body
>   of the web request.

It uses registered instances of `HttpMessageConverter` to deserialize the request body into an object of the annotated parameter type.

And the `@RequestParam` javadoc states

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to
>   a web request parameter.

1. Spring binds the body of the request to the parameter annotated with `@RequestBody`.
2. Spring binds request parameters from the request body (url-encoded parameters) to your method parameter. Spring will use the name of the parameter, ie. `name`, to map the parameter.
3. Parameters are resolved in order. The `@RequestBody` is processed first. Spring will consume all the `HttpServletRequest` `InputStream`. When it then tries to resolve the `@RequestParam`, which is by default `required`, there is no request parameter in the query string or what remains of the request body, ie. nothing. So it fails with 400 because the request can't be correctly handled by the handler method.
4. The handler for `@RequestParam` acts first, reading what it can of the `HttpServletRequest` `InputStream` to map the request parameter, ie. the whole query string/url-encoded parameters. It does so and gets the value `abc` mapped to the parameter `name`. When the handler for `@RequestBody` runs, there's nothing left in the request body, so the argument used is the empty string.
5. The handler for `@RequestBody` reads the body and binds it to the parameter. The handler for `@RequestParam` can then get the request parameter from the URL query string.
6. The handler for `@RequestParam` reads from both the body and the URL query String. It would usually put them in a `Map`, but since the parameter is of type `String`, Spring will serialize the `Map` as comma separated values. The handler for `@RequestBody` then, again, has nothing left to read from the body.

Comment: Suppose for case 4), Post Body is `name=abc&age=2`, then according to your explanation name should be `abc` and body should be `&age=2` but actual result is name is `abc` and body is _empty_.

Comment: @abhihello123 It reads the whole url encoded form parameters. So the whole `name=abc&age=2`.

Comment: but if I put another @RequestParam it puts 2 into age. That means name reads only abc. sorry for bugging.

Comment: @abhihello123 Yes, in that case, the full query string has been read and the next `@RequestParam` can be built from it. The parameters are stored in a map that can be checked each time for request params.

Comment: Thank You. Was reading spring docs but these points were not that clear.

Comment: @abhihello123 If you have **a lot** of patience. Download the source jars and use a debugger while sending a request and step through the code. The class you want to see is `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`, which does handling for `@RequestParam`.

Answer (score 7):

It's too late to answer this question, but it could help for new readers,
It seems version issues. I ran all these tests with spring 4.1.4 and found that the order of `@RequestBody` and `@RequestParam` doesn't matter.

1. same as your result
2. same as your result
3. gave `body= "name=abc"`, and `name = "abc"`
4. Same as 3.
5. `body ="name=abc"`, `name = "xyz,abc"`
6. same as 5.

Comment: How can we resolve this in case of 5. where we would want the request params but empty body?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of not very straight forward Servlet specification. If you are working with a native `HttpServletRequest` implementation you cannot get both the URL encode body and the parameters. Spring does some workarounds, which make it even more strange and nontransparent.

In such cases Spring (version 3.2.4) re-renders a body for you using data from the `getParameterMap()` method. It mixes GET and POST parameters and breaks the parameter order. The class, which is responsible for the chaos is `ServletServerHttpRequest`. Unfortunately it cannot be replaced, but the class `StringHttpMessageConverter` can be.

The clean solution is unfortunately not simple:

1. Replacing `StringHttpMessageConverter`. Copy/Overwrite the original class adjusting method `readInternal()`.
2. Wrapping `HttpServletRequest` overwriting `getInputStream()`, `getReader()` and `getParameter*()` methods.

In the method StringHttpMessageConverter#readInternal following code must be used:

```
    if (inputMessage instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
        ServletServerHttpRequest oo = (ServletServerHttpRequest)inputMessage;
        input = oo.getServletRequest().getInputStream();
    } else {
        input = inputMessage.getBody();
    }
```

Then the converter must be registered in the context.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true/false">
        <bean class="my-new-converter-class"/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

The step two is described here: [Http Servlet request lose params from POST body after read it once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210645)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just change the @RequestParam default required status to false so that HTTP response status code 400 is not generated. This will allow you to place the Annotations in any order you feel like.

```
@RequestParam(required = false)String name
```

Comment: Yes, response status code 400 won't be generated. But he also won't be able to get the value of @RequestParam (if it's passed) anyway!