# JQuery AJAX strange behaviour with parameters (Spring's @ModelAttribute)

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, modelattribute

I'm trying to pass a Map< String, String> to Spring via Ajax using @ModelAttribute notation.
With IntelliJ's REST client, I just have to add the "infos[KEY]" param with value "VALUE" to get the corresponding key/value couple populated in the hashmap.

I'm trying to reproduce the same behaviour with JQuery

```
function update()
{
     $.ajax(
          {
            type: "PATCH",
            url: "url",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {"infos[TheAnswer]": "42"},
            success: function(data)
              {
                alert("OK");
              }
          });
}
```

But Spring controller can't get to populate my model.
Here it is (but i shouldn't be the problem because as I said IntelliJ's REST client works fine)

```
public class ExtraInfos implements Serializable
{
    protected HashMap<String, String> infos = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public HashMap<String, String> getInfos()
    {
        return infos;
    }

    public void setInfos(HashMap<String, String> infos)
    {
        this.infos = infos;
    }
}
```

Here's my controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public
@ResponseBody
Contact updateContact(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                      @ModelAttribute ExtraInfos infos)
{
    return this.service.update(id, infos);
 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well using this controller

//Just an example

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/test/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Integer extra(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody ExtraInfos extraInfos){
            System.out.println(id);
            System.out.println(extraInfos.getInfos());

            return 1;
        }
```

The thing here is as the other previously mentioned you need to send the object for ExtraInfos.

If we suppose that this is an example value for ExtraInfos

```
ExtraInfos = {infos:{"key":"value"}}
```

Our mapper will create the ExtraInfos object with it.

Doing this ajax call (in this case for this mapper).

```
$.ajax({
    url:"test/23123",
    type:"post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:JSON.stringify(ExtraInfos)
})
```

Output on the console:

```
23123
{key=value}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes is the answer wrong? If it is it will be a pleasure to erase it.

Comment: Wasn't me. Anyway, it works great now, event with "PUT" method. I am pretty sure I tried it when Shay Elkayam answered me, but I probably messed it up. Thanks!

Comment: Yw i tried  also with PATCH and it worked for me. If you want to still use PATCH.

Comment: I am now facing a problem. Let's say I have a controller with both "@RequestBody ExtraInfos extraInfos" and "@RequestParam("something") Long something". What query should I make with JQuery to specify that only a part of the data is json-encoded?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468572/spring-mvc-why-not-able-to-use-requestbody-and-requestparam-together

Comment: It Seems that when we use the requestParam spring binds the full request body to that variable, that's why the requestParam fails because @requestBody consumes all the body you can add it to the POJO of extraInfos or send it as PathVariable

Answer (score 2):

String `modelAttribute` doesn't receive the data the way you sent it (json object).

**EDIT**

The easiest way for you should be to the following:

AJAX:

```
$.ajax(
          {
            type: "PATCH",
            url: "url",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {TheAnswer: "42"},
            success: function(data)
              {
                alert("OK");
              }
          });
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public @ResponseBody Contact updateContact(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                          @RequestBody ExtraInfos infos){
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither the first nor the second solution works.
The second one looked attractive though.

Comment: Sorry. lose the type: patch also. I didn't notice it. I updated it in my answer too.

Comment: Also, in order to use the first option, you should send all the fields of ExtraInfos object on the ajax json structure.

Comment: If I drop the type, then the request becomes a GET (by default) request and then the server throws a "405 Method not allowed"

Comment: so use type: 'post' both on the controller and the ajax.

Comment: Yes, but I want the method to be PATCH since I'm updating something.

Comment: So use the first method, and add all the fields to the ajax structure on the javascript side. It didn't work for you because you sent only "TheAnswer" and not all the fields in the ExtraInfos class

Comment: ExtraInfos only contains one field. I'll try the first one again maybe I did it wrong

Comment: send it as {theAnswer: 42} and use @RequestBody

Comment: I've edited my answer to the simplest solution. copy and paste it, I believe it should work.

Comment: Have you managed to get it working with the update I've posted?

Comment: I didn't tried it because Eduardo's answer worked. Anyway I think you meant contantType instead of dataType no?
Anyway thank you!