# Can I tell spring to ignore query parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

If I submit this form:

```
<form id="confirmForm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="guid" value="guidval"/>
</form>
```

to this url:

`/AltRT?guid=guidval`

mapped to this controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)    
public String indexPost(@RequestParam String guid)
```

I am getting both values for my guid. So the value of `guid` is `guidval,guidval`. I would like to only get the value from the form.

Is there any way tell Spring to ignore query string parameters?

EDIT for more clarification: The query string is left over from another (get) request. So, if I could clear the query string that would work as well. Also, I do not want edit the `name` of the form input because I want this post endpoint to be available to other services without having to change them as well.

Comment: Why are you using a query string, if your intent is to submit it in your hidden field?

Comment: Why don't you name the form input to something else, like guidVal?

Comment: @QuoVadis and j will See edit

Comment: It is better to take it out of the URL querystring. But [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468572/spring-mvc-why-not-able-to-use-requestbody-and-requestparam-together) (example 5) to a very similar question suggests using both `RequestBody` and `RequestParam` - in that order, as such: `public String indexPost(@RequestBody String guid, @RequestParam String guid2)`

Comment: @Vic I would prefer the post method to not be dependent on the parameter existing in the query string

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do so because the query string will be sent in the HTTP message body of a POST request, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

There are two ways I could think of now

1. set the form attribute action

   ```
   <form id="confirmForm" method="POST" action="AltRT">
       <input type="hidden" name="guid" value="guidval" />
   </form>
   ```
2. convert the form data into JSON object to send it over and then catch it with `@RequestBody` in Spring if you have to use the original URL.