# Java, JS : Tomcat refusing to call this method, unsupported media type

Tags: javascript, java, spring, tomcat

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which for this single method I am getting an error as `Unsupported media type`. None of the other methods have this problem. Any help would be nice. Thank you-.

Java Code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setnotificationlevels")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    boolean setNotificationLevels(@RequestParam("groupid") long groupid, @RequestBody GroupMembers member) {
        System.out.println("Set notification levels is called. ");
        return this.groupMembersService.setNotificationLevels(member, groupid);
    }
```

JS code :

```
setEmailNotifications : function (groupid, settings){
            return $.ajax({
                url: "/setnotificationlevels?groupid=" + groupid,
                type: 'POST',
                cache:false,
                data : JSON.stringify(settings),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
        },
```

Error log :

```
description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is your `member` parameter correctly set? See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468572/spring-mvc-why-not-able-to-use-requestbody-and-requestparam-together)

Comment: @barbsan : What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that 4th example from this link is similar to your case. Accepted answer there explains that data in `@RequestBody` is lost when you have both `@RequestBody` and `@RequestParam` specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tell your java code that its a post or get http methd:

@RequestMapping(value = url, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public@ResponseBody StringOrAnyResponseObject fName(@RequestBody final Object o)
{}

and in your js:
in any function
return $http.post(url,parameterMap);

Comment: What about request param?

Comment: u can put it in map and send it along and recieve in requestbody.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do that ? Thanks.

Comment: why do u need requestparam seperately?

Comment: I don't, but I don't know how to put it inside a map, I don't know much abt JS.

Comment: in js:
replace parameterMap with
{'variableName1':data,
'variableName2':data}

and in java replace Object o with
Map<String,String> object
in side method u can get
data=object.get('key');

Comment: Yes, this worked, but I dont understand why it didnt work with both of them in a single method

Comment: it will work u just have to tell js: which parameter is body which is params

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"` to @RequestMapping annotation.

Comment: its by default, no need to add the consumes since the default deserializer is Jackson