# Multipartfile parameter order precedence causing error

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data

Basically, I am sending two parameters , one a String and the other a file to my controller in Spring Boot . In the action, when I receive the file first and then the String next, like so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatemedia", method = RequestMethod.PATCH,consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> updateMedia(@RequestParam(value ="file") MultipartFile fileToUpload , @RequestParam(value = "keyId") String keyId )
```

everything is fine and I am able to access the String and the file correctly.

But when I change the order of the parameters , like so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatemedia", method = RequestMethod.PATCH,consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> updateMedia( @RequestParam(value = "keyId") String keyId , @RequestParam(value ="file") MultipartFile fileToUpload )
```

and send the params through Postman, I am hitting the below error[image]

I researched a lot but am not able to understand this behaviour.

Comment: It works either way.

Comment: As @pvpkiran already stated. Both should work. Please provide a minimal example on github for example to reproduce this. Just provide two controllers with those two endpoints and i will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you send `keyId` in body while it's declared as `@RequestParam`
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html .
`@RequestParam` has nothing to deal with request body, it's passed in request url.
What about your example, the first approach works, because your method expects one `@RequestPart`, the others are ignored.

Comment: Not so , please have a look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468572/spring-mvc-why-not-able-to-use-requestbody-and-requestparam-together

Also, I posted the question wrong, I was using @RequestParam for both the params