# Unable to change filter mapping spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httprequest

I've got following class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean slspServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean testServlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(new TestServlet());
        testServlet.addUrlMappings("/*");
        testServlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
        return TestServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean aliveServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean aliveServlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(new AliveServlet());
        aliveServlet.addUrlMappings("/alive/*");
        aliveServlet.setLoadOnStartup(3);
        return aliveServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean templateDownloaderServlet(){
        ServletRegistrationBean templateDownloader = new ServletRegistrationBean(new TemplateDownloaderServlet());
        templateDownloader.addUrlMappings("/template/download/*");
        templateDownloader.setLoadOnStartup(2);
        return templateDownloader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean endOfGenerationThreadServlet(){
        ServletRegistrationBean endOfGenerationThread = new ServletRegistrationBean(new EndOfGenerationThreadServlet());
        endOfGenerationThread.addUrlMappings("/endofgenerationthread/*");
        endOfGenerationThread.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return endOfGenerationThread;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(){
        ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DispatcherServlet());
        dispatcherServlet.setName("dispatcherServlet");
        dispatcherServlet.addUrlMappings("/dispatcher/*");
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean errorPageFilter(){
        FilterRegistrationBean errorPageFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean(new ErrorPageFilter(), dispatcherServlet());
        errorPageFilter.addUrlPatterns("/test/*");
        return errorPageFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean characterEncodingFilter(){
        FilterRegistrationBean characterEncodingFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CharacterEncodingFilter(), dispatcherServlet());
        characterEncodingFilter.addUrlPatterns("/test/*");
        return characterEncodingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean hiddenHttpMethodFilter(){
        FilterRegistrationBean hiddenHttpMethodFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean(new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(), dispatcherServlet());
        hiddenHttpMethodFilter.addUrlPatterns("/test/*");
        return hiddenHttpMethodFilter;
    }


}
```

What am I trying to do is change filter mapping of hiddenHttpMethodFilter, characterEncodingFilter, errorPageFilter so for that I have mapping /test/*.
When I start application I can see that it defaults to "/*"

```
Mapping servlet: 'testServlet' to [/*]
Mapping servlet: 'aliveServlet' to [/alive/*]
Mapping servlet: 'templateDownloaderServlet' to [/template/download/*]
Mapping servlet: 'endOfGenerationThreadServlet' to [/endofgenerationthread/*]
Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/dispatcher/*]
Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
```

What am I missing or what's wrong with my config? I'm on spring-boot 1.2.5.

There is another problem with filters (I think that's in filters).  When I want to access `request.getInputstream()` in my testServlet it's already read. I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210645/http-servlet-request-lose-params-from-post-body-after-read-it-once) and tried to implement RequestWrapper, but it's too late in my testServlet to wrap the request, because inputstream was read. So can somebody help me how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FilterRegistrationBean` bean named `hiddenHttpMethodFilter` is being overridden by the `OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter` bean of the same name that's created by Spring Boot's auto-configuration. There's a log message that tells you this is happening:

```
2015-08-27 16:13:54.268  INFO 70942 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=sampleWebFreeMarkerApplication; factoryMethodName=hiddenHttpMethodFilter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in sample.freemarker.SampleWebFreeMarkerApplication] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=hiddenHttpMethodFilter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
```

You need to rename your `hiddenHttpMethodFilter` method. Also, if you want to configure the registration of a `Filter` or `Servlet` that Boot auto-configures, there's no need to create the `Filter` or `Servlet` yourself. Instead, you should have the existing one injected into your `@Bean` method:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean hiddenHttpMethodFilterRegistration(
        HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/test/*");
    return registration;
}
```

You might also want to consider setting the `server.servlet-path` property in `application.properties` as an easier way of configuring the dispatcher servlet's mapping.

Comment: That's correct. Rename of method helped me. Thank you wery much. By server.servlet-mapping you probably thought server.servlet-path. This is mapping only for DispatcherServlet?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `server.servlet-path`. I've corrected my answer. And, yes, it's only used to configure the dispatcher servlet's path.