# How can I read request body multiple times in Spring 'HandlerMethodArgumentResolver'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to resolve some certain parameters of `RequestMapping` methods, to extract values from request body and validates them and inject them into certain annotated parameters.

```
@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                              NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    // 1, get corresponding input parameter from NativeWebRequest
    // 2, validate
    // 3, type convertion and assemble value to return
    return null;
}
```

The biggest problem is that I find out that `HttpServletRequest`(get from `NativeWebRequest`) cannot read input stream(some parameters are in the request body) **more than one time**. So how can I retrieve `Inputstream`/`Reader` or the request body more than one time?

Comment: One solution could be to use a ThreadLocal to store params inside a filter from request and then use them anywhere in your code at any number of times.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia This may help. But one problem is, if I save the body into the threadlocal(by calling HttpServletRequest.getReader/getInputStream), this will never be called again. Event in the controller layer, I cannot declare "@RequestBody String body"(which may throw an exception by Spring), because Spring cannot read the input stream anymore.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can add a filter, intercept the current `HttpServletRequest` and wrap it in a custom `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. In your custom `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, you read the request body and cache it and then implement `getInputStream` and `getReader` to read from the cached value. Since after wrapping the request, the cached value is always present, you can read the request body multiple times:

```
@Component
public class CachingRequestBodyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest currentRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        MultipleReadHttpRequest wrappedRequest = new MultipleReadHttpRequest(currentRequest);
        chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

After this filter, everybody will see the `wrappedRequest` which has the capability of being read multiple times:

```
public class MultipleReadHttpRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream cachedContent;

    public MultipleReadHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        // Read the request body and populate the cachedContent
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        // Create input stream from cachedContent
        // and return it
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        // Create a reader from cachedContent
        // and return it
    }
}
```

For implementing `MultipleReadHttpRequest`, you can take a look at [`ContentCachingRequestWrapper`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.java) from spring framework which is basically does the same thing.

This approach has its own disadvantages. First of all, it's somewhat inefficient, since for every request, request body is being read at least two times. The other important drawback is if your request body contains `10 GB` worth of stream, you read that `10 GB` data and even worse bring that into memory for further examination.

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution so far. But the efficiency is truly a big problem. I think i'll have to find a way to restrict the input stream size in case anyone engage in sabotage or something. As for the request body read twice at least, I think it is acceptable since I only accept json formated input strings from the request body which normally less than 1kb/pr.

Comment: Complete example is available in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129256/364401

Comment: by the way, ContentCachingRequestWrapper does't do the same thing, it allows to get the data from cache but you have to first read the real data. It's useful for logging  but for other things not very well.

Comment: I wanted to use it for multipart/form-data but that's also  not supported by ContentCachingRequestWrapper

Comment: An interesting fact that for some reason Spring's `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` doesn't really "cache" anything (as what I found via trials and errors). On the contrary, a solution referenced in a sister thread by @Stim, worked perfectly - the one that requires you to implement your own `MultiReadHttpServletRequest` wrapper.

Comment: I had problems with ContentCachingRequestWrapper when trying to get a body inside a logging filter. Spring MVC then failed to get a request body the second time from an input stream.