# Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing

Tags: spring, interceptor

I have and Interceptor and for some reasons i have to read POSTED date included in `HttpServletRequest` like this:

```
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } else {
        stringBuilder.append("");
    }
```

after this action i get 400 bad request for ajax
Failed to read HTTP message: `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring provides a class called `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` which extends `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. This class caches all content read from
the `getInputStream()` and `getReader()`
and allows this content to be retrieved via a `getContentAsByteArray()` . So we can retrieve `InputStream` multiple times for this purpose. This ability provided by method blow in `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` :

```
@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    if (this.inputStream == null) {
            this.inputStream = new ContentCachingInputStream(getRequest().getInputStream());
    }
    return this.inputStream;
}
```

This class fix character encoding issues  for `UTF-8` with method below:

```
@Override
public String getCharacterEncoding() {
    String enc = super.getCharacterEncoding();
    return (enc != null ? enc : WebUtils.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_ENCODING);
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.java) is full detail in `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` .

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have a method handler like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/somewhere", method = POST)
public SomeResponse someHandler(@RequestBody String body, ...) { ... }
```

And you read the `HttpServletRequest`'s `InputStream` in your interceptor. Since you can read the `InputStream` only once, when spring tries to read the `InputStream` in order to populate the `@RequestBody` method parameter, it fails and complains with `HttpMessageNotReadableException`.

If you seriously need to read the request body multiple times, you should add a filter and decorate the `HttpServletRequest` in order to add a `Multiple Read` feature. For more information you can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34806876/1393484).

Comment: Its true. I changed it to filter. its fine but it changes content to non-unicode. what about this?

Comment: Override the `getCharacterEncoding` method in your filter to return the `UTF-8` as character encoding