# Spring Cloud Gateway - request stuck when trying to read request body in web filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm new to Spring Cloud Gateway (spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE). I try to read the request body from a web filter and the request is just stuck and cannot flow through the chain. Sample code:

```
@Component
public class TestFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestFilter.class);

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest = exchange.getRequest();
        try {
            /* whenever I put the following line. The request cannot get through */
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Mono.from(serverHttpRequest.getBody()).toFuture().get().asByteBuffer();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

If I remove the getBody() line, everything works fine. Any clue? Thx!

Comment: You can only read the body once after that it has been consumed and cannot be read again. You will have to create a wrapper which makes it possible to read the body multiple times (just like a classic servlet filter wrapping a `HttpServletRequest` and copying all read bytes to a `byte[]` so it can be read again).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [How can I read request body multiple times in Spring 'HandlerMethodArgumentResolver'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804205/how-can-i-read-request-body-multiple-times-in-spring-handlermethodargumentresol)

This remark explains it pretty accurate:

> The biggest problem is that I find out that HttpServletRequest(get from NativeWebRequest) cannot read input stream(some parameters are in the request body) more than one time