# How to print a REST JSON request/response in the logs?

Tags: java, json, regex, rest

I'm calling a JSON REST service and in the returned response, I have escape characters.

I want to avoid the escape characters (to have them interpreted), and pretty print a JSON response. I cannot use GSON because of some constraints. I've tried the pretty print option, but that doesn't seem to work.

All of this has to be done in JAVA.

For eg.

```
String originalString = "{\n    "name":"xyz",\n    "age":"23"\n}"
```

is available as a String. This has to be converted to

```
String newString = {"name":"xyz","age":"23"}
```

If possible, I should be able to pretty print it in the logs with proper indentation - something like,

```
{
    "name":"xyz",
    "age":"23"
}
```

I'm getting the original string in the logs from a REST JSON service response. The new string can be printed somehow in the logs (StringBuilder or some other way).

EDIT: Going up one level, the reason this question was asked is to print the request/responses in the logs. I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210645/http-servlet-request-lose-params-from-post-body-after-read-it-once) as an input while doing it for the request. However, after logging the request, I'm facing an issue logging the response. The problem reads,

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0209E: Writer already obtained
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue? The problem I believe is being able to cache the response like it is being done for the request in the example link above.

Comment: Where do you want it to be pretty printed? On a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Apache commons-lang StringEscapeUtils class you can achieve this. Below is the snippet for the same.

StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(originalString);