# HTTP raw text POST request

Tags: java, http, servlets

I need to calculate the hash of my raw HTTP post request and compare it with the signature hash in the header of the same in Java. The problem is, I have tried multiple methods but I am unable to extract the exact POST request sent. Attached is the request:

[image]

I need exact same string (along with all the % and other symbols) since even a single space difference would generate an incorrect hash. Can we use custom-filters here, if yes then how exactly?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using servlet or jersey? In servlet you can get the request's raw stream and convert to string. `HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()` or [getReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader%28%29).

e.g

```
InputStream body = request.getInputStream();
// ..
```

Edit: Adding code that I have, which works.

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
        //this convertStreamToString is my internal method. You can have any your own conversion API
        System.out.println("----"+convertStreamToString(is)); 
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Caveat: When you do that, you might not be able to use `getParameter()` any more, so you'd have to process the content yourself too. As javadoc of [`getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) says: *If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via `getInputStream()` or `getReader()` can interfere with the execution of this method.*

Comment: That's a nice point. Thanks @Andreas. Can one get getParameters() first and then call the stream/reader? I need to revert back to API.

Comment: I think the problem is that if content is streamed (client decides that), then content can only be processed once. `getInputStream()`, `getReader()`, and `getParameter()` (and it's cousins) all *consume* the content. I think that if the content was sent in full, i.e. not streamed, they would all work, hence the "can interfere" in the javadoc. By streaming I mean that content is chunked, i.e. `content-length` header is not given.

Comment: getReader() and getInputStream() does not help. They return null. However, I am getting values in getParamterMap(), but htis returns a map<String, String[]>, but my problem is that I need exactly same raw data without any changes.

Comment: Call this before calling any parameter. Like @Andreas pointed out the stream might have already been read and reset once you call getparameter().

Comment: nopes..its still not working...even if only getReader() is called...The only hope I see here is getParameter family, but it doesnt return the exact data..

Comment: I am surprised as it works for me.  I just had a servlet with post method and then I did `InputStream is = request.getInputStream();` and then `System.out.println("----"+convertStreamToString(is));` I got the exact full string. Off course convertStreamToString is my internal method.

Comment: You problem might be a `Filter` that calls `getParameter()`, which therefore consumes the content. In that case you have two options: 1) Remove the filter. 2) Put a new `Filter` first, which loads all content into memory, i.e. caching it, and then provides that content repeatedly. See [Http Servlet request lose params from POST body after read it once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10210645/5221149) for how.

Comment: Thanks! let me try..will update in sometime!

Comment: It is working now..fynally! Thanks a lot for helpful suggestions!