# Grails filter Error occurred initializing command object

Tags: grails, filter

Grails 2.5.6.

I use a filter class to validate all my requests for XSS attacks. If a parameter might be harmful we simply do not forward the request to the desired interface.

This workflow works fine except for cases where there is a command object used as a interface argument. The variable is simply empty and without any params.

```
if (paramsValid) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response)
}else {
    println("ERROR");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setStatus(400);
    out.print('{"success": false, "data": "Error validating request parameters"}');
    out.flush();
    return;
}
```

Then inside a conttroller interface:

```
def save(MappingCmd mapping) {

    println(mapping);
```

The mappingCmd class members are always empty. The functionally works fine without the filter. How can I make this work?

Comment: What is going on before `if(paramsValid)`?  If you are reading the body of the request then that would prevent the command object data binding stuff from working.

Comment: Yes I am reading the request..because that is exactly what I need to do. I have tested further and basically anything I do with the request prevents correct behavior. Any ideas? Can i clone the request object?

Comment: I think this is my problem: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10035

Comment: Solved my problem using this sollution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210645/http-servlet-request-lose-params-from-post-body-after-read-it-once