# Spring MVC Controller method mapping using form body

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-boot

I'm building a small application to serve as a client for some third party library here at work. The API states that a `Webhook`is needed to respond some asynchronous events, but all their methods have the very same signature, apart from a changing `_method` field between the calls. For example, I have a `_method` = `ping`, `media`, etc.

I'd like to have separate methods on my controller to respond for each one of these methods. If the app allowed me to specify different URLs for each method it would be easy to use Spring MVC's `@RequestMapping` for each one of them. But I have to specify a single endpoint to receive all calls.

Is there a way (for example using Spring's `HttpMessageConverter` or something like that) to map different controller methods based on what the Request Body is? I've already tried with `@RequestBody`, `@RequestParam` but didn't seem to find anything.

I really, *really* didn't want to use a bunch of `case, switch` methods on a front controller to dispatch actions based on my `_method` field that comes with my POST data, so I happen to believe someone had this problem before and solved it intelligently.

Thanks a lot!

### Edit 1: Providing source code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/webhooks")
public class WebhookController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"_method=ping"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String ping(){
        return "pong";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"_method=media"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String media(){
        return "media";
    }
}
```

This is the answer:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1440875190389,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException",
  "message": "Parameter conditions \"_method=ping\" not met for actual request parameters: ",
  "path": "/webhooks"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, I got it working. The answer is a bit tricky so I wanted to register it here should anyone have such problem.

@Neil McGuigan pointed me on the right direction on his comment but I didn't pay attention at first. The main culprit here is a very, very, *very* bad API design on our remote application's side.

`_method` is a field used to specify non-standard HTTP verbs such as `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`, `TRACE` and so on. This field is filtered by `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` and the `HttpServletRequest` is wrapped with this 'new' method. You can see at [the file's source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java#L52) how it works.

As I wanted this `_method` field to get thru the filter without modifying the whole request (and causing the errors because there's no such verb as `ping`or `message` on `RequestMethod) I firstly had to deactivate the filter. This could be done by two ways:

1. I could stop Spring Boot from automagically configuring Spring MVC, skipping `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` from being loaded when the `ApplicationContext` was loaded. As you can imagine this is a BIG, BIG, BIIIIG **NO** because, well, [things](http://giphy.com/gifs/HhTXt43pk1I1W/fullscreen) could happen.
2. I could use a `FilterRegistrationBean` to disable the bad filter. Pretty simple and straightforward, this was the method I chose to use:

   ```
   @Bean
   public FilterRegistrationBean registration(HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
       FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
       registration.setEnabled(false);
       return registration;
   }
   ```

Last but not least, I decided to give `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` a little extension to somehow *improve* how the requests were getting thru. The Java EE Spec is pretty clear on the Servlet Spec Commandments where it states:

> Thou *should* not alter your request on your side. You must respect the sender (something like that)

Though I agree with this, for the sake of my mental stability I decided to alter it anyway. To achieve this, we can use a simple `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, override the chosen methods and filter the original request with the wrapped part. I ended up doing something like this:

```
public class WhatoolsHiddenHttpMethodFilter extends OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String paramValue = request.getParameter(OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter.DEFAULT_METHOD_PARAM);
        if("POST".equals(request.getMethod()) && StringUtils.hasLength(paramValue)) {
            String method = paramValue.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
            List<String> whatoolsMethods = Arrays.asList("ping", "message", "carbon", "media", "media_carbon", "ack");
            if(whatoolsMethods.contains(paramValue)){
                WhatoolsHiddenHttpMethodFilter.HttpMethodRequestWrapper wrapper = new WhatoolsHiddenHttpMethodFilter
                        .HttpMethodRequestWrapper(request, "POST", paramValue);
                filterChain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
            } else {
                WhatoolsHiddenHttpMethodFilter.HttpMethodRequestWrapper wrapper = new WhatoolsHiddenHttpMethodFilter
                        .HttpMethodRequestWrapper(request, method, null);
                filterChain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
            }
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    private static class HttpMethodRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        private final String method;

        private final String whatoolsMethod;

        public HttpMethodRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String method, String whatoolsMethod) {
            super(request);
            this.method = method;
            this.whatoolsMethod = whatoolsMethod;
        }

        @Override
        public String getMethod() {
            return this.method;
        }

        @Override
        public String getHeader(String name) {
            if("x-whatools-method".equals(name)){
                return this.whatoolsMethod;
            }
            return super.getHeader(name);
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
            List<String> names = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
            if(this.whatoolsMethod != null){
                names.add("x-whatools-method");
            }
            return Collections.enumeration(names);
        }
    }
}
```

So, what this does is to wrap the request with a new `x-whatools-method` header when the header is in my `whatoolsMethods` list. With this, I can easily use `@RequestMapping`'s `headers` property and map the requests to the correct controller methdods.

Back to the initial question, I'm almost sure (well, 99,95% should be completely sure but let's not risk it) the `params` property on `@RequestMapping` works only for request parameters on GET URIs, e.g `http://foo.bar/?baz=42`. It won't work filtering parameters sent on the request's body.

Thanks Neil for your guidance, even if small! I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use params in a request mapping:

@RequestMapping(value="/foo", params={"_method=ping"})

Assuming these are post parameters that is

`params` DOES work for POST, I promise you

Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test1")
public class ParamTestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody String getA(){
        return "A";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"b"})
    @ResponseBody String getB(){
        return "B";
    }
}
```

Here's my test:

[image]

Comment: That's weird, Neil. That didn't work. Firstly I thought it would too, but it seems `params` only carry GET parameters, no?

Comment: Works for me. Do you have a HiddenHttpMethodFilter ?

Comment: I posted the outcome on the main question. It didn't work!