# Java request getInputStream return empty stream

Tags: java, post, inputstream, filenames

I've got a problem with getInputStream from doPost request and setting filename before. It's giving me a file with right filename but empty file 0kB. If I'll comment setting fileName than I'll get not empty file.

My process: From android apps I'm archiving PDF file to upload server like http POST. At server doPost is like below method.

How to set filename and get not empty file?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    String fileName = null;
    //Get all the parts from request and write it to the file on server
    //getFileName return filename
    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        fileName = getFileName(part);
    }
    File saveFile = new File(SAVE_DIR + fileName);

    // opens input stream of the request for reading data
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();

    // opens an output stream for writing file
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = -1;

    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);           
    }
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();

    // sends response to client
    response.getWriter().print("UPLOAD DONE");

}
```

Edit:

```
private String getFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    System.out.println("content-disposition header= " + contentDisp);
    String[] tokens = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String token : tokens) {
        if (token.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

**Solution**:

```
//Get the right Part
 final Part filePart = request.getPart("uploadedfile");
 //Writes file to location 
 filePart.write(filePart.getSubmittedFileName());
```

Comment: What does your `getFileName(part);` method do?

Comment: The content of `InputStream` can only be consumed once. This happens in `request.getParts()` I guess, so the stream when accessing it a second time is empty. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522568/why-is-httpservletrequest-inputstream-empty

Comment: Note that the stream returned from `HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()` is not just the uploaded file. It's the stream of the entire request, including all the part headers. To access just the uploaded file, you need the `getInputStream()` of the specific `Part`.

Comment: @Stepan Don't paste code in comments, it's unreadable. Edit your original post to include the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Part` offers a `getInputStream()` method, so you should use that instead of `request.getInputStream();` when you're dealing with parts.

*However...*

[Part.write()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) is a convenience method to write this uploaded item to disk, so you can just use `part.write(SAVE_DIR + part.getSubmittedFileName());` and it's all handled for you (note that `getSubmittedFileName()` is available only for Servlet 3.1).

Comment: Do you have some example how to getPart? How to get the "name" which is at uploaded file?

Comment: @Stepan What part of my `part.write(SAVE_DIR + part.getSubmittedFileName());` was unclear? You're already getting the parts in your original code, so how can you ask me "how to do it"? Or is that not your code?

Comment: I mean how I know which name I use in getPart?

Comment: @Stepan Well that depends on which name (if any) you're giving it in the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Do outputstream.flush() before doing outputstream.close()