# get httpservletrequest inside dofilter method of filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Filter to intercept each request, where in filter I can get only ServletRequest inputstream, which is returning empty input stream, to get the input stream.It seems that I need to get the HttpServletRequest.
How to achieve this?
I tried casting as well as converting to httpservletrequest.
none of the ways, i was able to get value using

```
request.getParameter("aaa") //when request content type is multipart/file.
```

Answer (score 1):

`getInputStream()` is a part of `ServletRequest` interface, so even if you cast `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest` ( which extends from ServletRequest) the result will be the same.

Perhaps this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522613/5202500) will help you to find out why inputstream is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If the input stream is empty there was no request body. Getting the `HttpServletRequest` won't change that: in fact, you already have it.

Comment: If the input stream is empty but the parameters aren't, the parameters are available via, err, `request.getParameter()` and the input stream is, err, empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to type cast the "servletRequest" into "HttpServletRequest" inside my custom filter class. Below is the snippet,

```
public class SAMLFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;

        if(servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
            System.out.println("getInputStream = " + httpServletRequest.getInputStream());

        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT CAST");
        }


    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```