# HttpServletRequest params empty

Tags: grails

Trying to validate the params sent via  `HttpServletRequest` it seems that when accessing the `request.JSON` the params are deleted and cannot be accessed anymore.

More info here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10035

How can I validate the values without causing the params to be deleted? I have tried cloning the `HttpServletRequest` object and then work with that but without success.

```
HttpServletRequest sreq = (HttpServletRequest) request
println(sreq.JSON) //from this point params are gone
```

Comment: Request is in stream form so once you read stream data it does not remain there. For that you need to copy/clone data and read and again try to re-assign values to request.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522568/why-is-httpservletrequest-inputstream-empty

Comment: You're not cloning anything, you're just defining another variable that points to the same instance.

Comment: Yes I know..but also attempted cloning which I was unable to do... How can I solve this?

Comment: Solved my problem using this sollution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210645/http-servlet-request-lose-params-from-post-body-after-read-it-once