# How to get the raw POST data in Spring Boot controller

Tags: spring-boot, post, urlencode

I have a plain controller class `extends AbstractController` that I'm plugging into Spring's handler mapping mechanism, by creating a new `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` bean.

In my class I need to read the raw POST data, even when the Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is somewhat tricky in the Servlet specification, because in order to do that, you need to call `request.getInputStream()` or `request.getReader()` ***before*** you access any of the `request.getParameter*()` methods. Otherwise, the latter will consume the input stream and it will not be available anymore.

In my class I'm not calling any of the `getParameter*()` methods, but I'm still seeing an empty request body when the Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Which means that Spring is calling one of the `getParameter*()` methods before it handles control over to my class.

Which class is doing that and how can I prevent it?

---

(Note to overzealous editors: this question is specific to Spring Boot. It is not a duplicate of other "raw POST data" questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

I just needed to disable the HiddenHttpMethodFilter, which I'm not using anyways:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=false
```

Comment: You might want to add the fact that you are using Spring Boot to your question, as it is quite relevant.

Comment: I faced a similar problem which is caused spring-mvc 5's build in request logging, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264125/3656774