# Postman POST request sends empty stream despite body being included

Tags: java, postman

I am using Postman to test an api I have written in Java. I am able to access the api itself (I see it when I debug), but the JSON object I am sending is received as empty. At the end of execution, an empty print is happening.

In the header configurations I have the following:
[image]

and in the body section I entered the following json:
[image]

My Java code:

```java
@POST
@Path("admin/save'")
public Response printInputText(@Context SecurityContext sc,InputStream incomingData) {

    String requestText = getStringFromInputStream(incomingData);
    System.out.println(requestText);
    if(requestText.equals("")){
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
    return Response.status(Status.OK).build();

}

public static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + System.lineSeparator());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

curl (changed the url a bit but I am getting to the url so it is not the issue):

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://uri.com/ui/rest/admin/save' \

--header 'Authorization: Basic QzUzMDY3Nzc6QWxlWEZlckczMg==' \

--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \

--data-raw '{
    "key": "value",
    "nextKey": "nextVal",
    "lastKey": "lastVal"
}'
```

Comment: URL you are trying to hit in POSTMAN?

Comment: Can you share curl from postman here?

Comment: I'd rather not specify the exact url, but my request is getting to it as I can see when I debug in Eclipse. I added the curl from postman. thanks!

Comment: I guess requestText  is json content with String. How did you return the response to postman?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Spring here because you didn't specify. Perhaps your InputStream is already being consumed by another part of the framework?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522568/why-is-httpservletrequest-inputstream-empty

Comment: I am indeed using Spring, sorry for the confusion. The thing is that the method printInputText() is the api itself. The stream is received by the api and undergoes no processing in the Java code beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing with `"data:"` and ending with `"\n\n"`, like this:

```
async def generate_stream(request: Request):

    async def stream_results():
        for i, token in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']):
            event = {
                "token": {
                    "id": i,
                    "text": token,
                    "logprob": 0.0,
                    "special": None
                }
            }
            event_data = "data:" + json.dumps(event) + "\n\n"
            yield event_data.encode("utf-8")

    return StreamingResponse(stream_results(), media_type='text/event-stream')
```

Comment: I don't understand. You posted Python code when the question is tagged "java" and this answer is identical to your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155405/why-postman-is-returning-empty-responses-in-sse-requests/78213462#78213462). Why?