# Why postman is returning empty responses in SSE requests?

Tags: python, postman, openai-api

So I am trying to create a Flask endpoint that will stream the response from OpenAI chatgpt API:

```
def get_report_stream(msg):
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(engine="gpt-4", messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": prompt()},
            {"role": "user", "content": str(msg['Val'])},
        ], stream=True)
    
    for line in completion:
        if 'content' in line['choices'][0]['delta']:
            yield line['choices'][0]['delta']['content']

@app.route("/load", methods=["POST"])
def load_bs_into_df():
    stream = request.form.get('stream', default=False, type=bool)
    file_path = 'input.xlsx'
    input_data = load_data_from_excel(file_path)
    if stream:
         return Response(stream_with_context(get_report_stream(input_data)), mimetype='text/event-stream')
    else:    
        report = get_report_whole(input_data)
        return {"df": input_data, "report": report}
```

When I run curl command:

```
curl -X POST -d "stream=true" http://127.0.0.1:5000/load
```

It will start streaming the response in the console.

But when I send request through postman then it will give some empty responses and thats it:

[image]

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm having the exact same issue and somehow your SO post is the only thing on the internet talking about it!

Comment: @Colin honestly I gave up but there is a new answer below, not sure if it can work for you, let me know

Answer (score -1):

To be properly displayed on Postman, the data must be formatted in the following way:

```py
class SseMessageEvent:
    def __init__(self, 
                 data: Union[str, Any], 
                 id: Optional[str] = None, 
                 type: Optional[str] = None, 
                 retry: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        self.data = data
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.retry = retry
```

`type` allows Postman to display the type and `data` the content.