# Best way to log the controller requests on error response

Tags: spring-boot, filter, log4j2, interceptor, spring-aop

Pesudocode :-

```
@RestController 
class Controller {

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAPI(@Valid @RequestBody Request request) {
        try {
            // success response.
        } catch (RequestParamsException e) {
            // log.error(e + request) log error and request.
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log.error(e + request) log error and request
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

}
```

We want to log the request for all error logs at the controller level. Simplest approach is that we can go to every api in all `controllers` and log the `request` there, Is there any better way we can do this for all APIs in spring using AOP/filters/interceptors somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better way! You could define a bean as follows:

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

}
```

In this class, you can add exception handlers for Spring exceptions, e.g.

```java
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatch(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex, WebRequest request) {
        final String message = Optional.ofNullable(ex.getRequiredType())
            .map(Class::getName)
            .map(className -> String.format("%s should be of type %s", ex.getName(), className))
            .orElseGet(ex::getMessage);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, message, BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
```

You can also add exception handlers for custom exceptions, e.g.

```java
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFoundException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, NOT_FOUND, request);
    }
```

where all exceptions you throw when an entity can't be found in the DB extend the `NotFoundException`.

You may also want to override certain methods from the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` super class, e.g.

```java
    @NotNull
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex,
                                                                          @NotNull HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                          @NotNull HttpStatus status,
                                                                          @NotNull WebRequest request) {
        final String message = String.format("%s parameter is missing", ex.getParameterName());
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, message, BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
```

A fallback for all other uncatched exceptions:

```java
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "An internal error occurred", INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }
```

Now to the logging part: you need to override the following method in order to log your errors in a custom way, please note that I return a special DTO `ApiError` when an exception is thrown:

```java
    @Override
    @NotNull
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(@NotNull Exception ex,
                                                             @Nullable Object body,
                                                             @NotNull HttpHeaders headers,
                                                             @NotNull HttpStatus status,
                                                             @NotNull WebRequest webRequest) {
        // Log
        final String errorId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletWebRequest) webRequest).getRequest();
        final String path = String.format("%s %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI());
        final BiConsumer<String, Exception> log = status.is4xxClientError() ? logger::info : logger::error;
        log.accept(String.format("%s returned for request %s, errorId is %s", status, path, errorId), ex);

        // Create API error
        final ApiError apiError = ApiError.builder()
            .errorId(errorId)
            .message(Optional.ofNullable(body)
                .filter(String.class::isInstance)
                .map(String.class::cast)
                .orElseGet(ex::getMessage))
            .build();

        // Return
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, headers, status);
    }
```

Depending on whether it is a 4xx or a 5xx error, I either log on `info` or `error` level. The `@ControllerAdvice` annotation instructs Spring to use this bean as exception handler for all Controllers, thereby being your global error handler.

Everything from above puzzled together (plus helper methods I use for the examples):

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    // ---------------
    // 400 Bad Request
    // ---------------

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatch(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex, WebRequest request) {
        final String message = Optional.ofNullable(ex.getRequiredType())
            .map(Class::getName)
            .map(className -> String.format("%s should be of type %s", ex.getName(), className))
            .orElseGet(ex::getMessage);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, message, BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

    // ---------------
    // 404 Bad Request
    // ---------------

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFoundException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, NOT_FOUND, request);
    }

    // -------------------------
    // 500 Internal Server Error
    // -------------------------

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "An internal error occurred", INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }

    // --------------
    // Helper methods
    // --------------

    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, HttpStatus httpStatus, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, ex.getMessage(), httpStatus, request);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, String errorMessage, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), status, request);
    }

    @Override
    @NotNull
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(@NotNull Exception ex,
                                                             @Nullable Object body,
                                                             @NotNull HttpHeaders headers,
                                                             @NotNull HttpStatus status,
                                                             @NotNull WebRequest webRequest) {
        // Log
        final String errorId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletWebRequest) webRequest).getRequest();
        final String path = String.format("%s %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI());
        final BiConsumer<String, Exception> log = status.is4xxClientError() ? logger::info : logger::error;
        log.accept(String.format("%s returned for request %s, errorId is %s", status, path, errorId), ex);

        // Create API error
        final ApiError apiError = ApiError.builder()
            .errorId(errorId)
            .message(Optional.ofNullable(body)
                .filter(String.class::isInstance)
                .map(String.class::cast)
                .orElseGet(ex::getMessage))
            .build();

        // Return
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, headers, status);
    }

}
```

Feel free to add more custom exceptions or Spring exceptions that occurr in the web layer and check out whether you want to override additional `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` methods like `handleMethodArgumentNotValid`!

Comment: where are we logging request body in handleExceptionInterval

Comment: Hi @tusharRawat, unfortunately this is not as easy to achieve as one might think. The problem is that Spring reads the request body and when you try to access it in the exception handler, it has already been read. As a consequence, trying to access the request body will only return an empty object as the Stream has been consumed before. For more information you can refer to this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522568/5151202

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [error handling and @ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling)

There you can have your common method to log errors

Comment: for ```@ControllerAdvice```, I have to rethrow the exceptions from controller right.

Comment: Either re-throw or just don't handle them in controller. It will be handled in advice.