# FindById() with a composite key

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a composite primary key made of planId and planDate, when the user gives me both this attributes I cant find a way to retrieve it from my Repo. Should findById work like this?

```
 public Plans assignPlansToMeds(Long id, Long planId, Date planDate) {

        Set<Meds> medsSet = null;
        Meds meds = medsRepo.findById(id).get();
        Plans plans = plansRepo.findById(planId, planDate).get();

        medsSet = plans.getAssignedMeds();

        medsSet.add(meds);
        plans.setAssignedMeds(medsSet);
        return plansRepo.save(plans);

    }
```

My Primary Key:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class PlansPKId implements Serializable {

    private long planId;

    private Date planDate; // format: yyyy-mm-dd
}
```

Plans entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "plans")

public class Plans {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PlansPKId plansPKId;

    @Column
    private String planName;

    @Column
    private String weekday;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Plan_Meds", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "planDate", referencedColumnName = "planDate"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "planId", referencedColumnName = "planId") }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private Set<Meds> assignedMeds = new HashSet<>();

}
```

where I ask for the planId and planDate:

```
@PutMapping("/medicine/{id}/assignToPlan/{planId}/date/{plandate}")
    public Plans assignMedToPlan(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable Long planId, @PathVariable Date planDate){

        return assignService.assignPlansToMeds(id, planId, planDate);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring `JpaRepository` only allows one type as the ID-type, as can be seen in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html). Therefore, `findById` will never accept two arguments.

You need to define your repository with your EmbeddedId-type as ID-type as follows:

```java
@Repository
public interface PlansRepository extends JpaRepository<Plans, PlansPKId> {
}
```

You can then call the `findById` method as follows:

```java
Plans plans = plansRepo.findById(new PlansPKId(planId, planDate))
    .orElseThrow(PlansNotFoundException.idAndDate(planId, planDate));
```

If you dont want to create a new `PlansPKId` instance for every query, you could also define a repository method as follows and let Spring derive the query based on the method name:

```java
Optional<Plans> findByPlansPKIdPlanIdAndPlansPKIdPlanDate(long planId, Date planDate);
```

If you don't like to have a cumbersome method name you could as well define a JPQL query and name the method as you like:

```java
@Query("select p from Plans p where p.plansPKId.planId = :planId and p.plansPKId.planDate = :planDate")
Optional<Plans> findByCompositeId(@Param("planId) long planId, @Param("planDate") Date planDate);
```

On a side note, I strongly encourage you to use `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` (depending on your needs) instead of the legacy `Date` class.

Moreover, you shouldn't call `get()` on an `Optional` without checking if it is present. I recently wrote [an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74769665/5151202) describing how you can create an elegant error handling. If you stuck to my example, you had to create a `NotFoundException` and then create the `PlansNotFoundException` which extends `NotFoundException`. by this means, everytime when a `PlansNotFoundException` is thrown in thread started by a web request, the user would receive a 404 response and a useful message if you implement it like this:

```java
public abstract class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    protected NotFoundException(final String object, final String identifierName, final Object identifier) {
        super(String.format("No %s found with %s %s", object, identifierName, identifier));
    }

    protected NotFoundException(final String object, final Map<String, Object> identifiers) {
        super(String.format("No %s found with %s", object,
                identifiers.entrySet().stream()
                        .map(entry -> String.format("%s %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" and "))));
    }

}
```

```java
public class PlansNotFoundException extends NotFoundException {

    private PlansNotFoundException(final Map<String, Object> identifiers) {
        super("plans", identifiers);
    }

    public static Supplier<PlansNotFoundException> idAndDate(final long planId, final Date planDate) {
        return () -> new PlansNotFoundException(Map.of("id", id, "date", date));
    }

}
```

For the `Meds` case:

```java
public class MedsNotFoundException extends NotFoundException {

    private MedsNotFoundException(final String identifierName, final Object identifier) {
        super("meds", identifierName, identifier);
    }

    public static Supplier<MedsNotFoundException> id(final long id) {
        return () -> new MedsNotFoundException("id", id);
    }

}
```

```java
Meds meds = medsRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(MedsNotFoundException.id(id));
```